# Is it ok to bring my concerns of missing my old position up?

Tags: professionalism, new-job, job-change

About 3 months ago I accepted a new position in my company in a different department. A career change in a way. My company and department specifically had hit a rough patch. At the time of me accepting my new position a new manager was brought in to fix the issues within my department and to directly oversee me and my two coworkers. I spent a few weeks working under this manager before leaving for my new position and enjoyed the support I had begun to recieve making the job bearable again. I had become unsure about leaving after meeting with this manager but I told myself I was making a good move to advance myself.

In my new position I began to learn a new skill, see a new side of the company, and the amount of over time I put in has decreased drastically. However, I'm worried that this job will not be enough for me now that I've spent a few months there. In my old position I was at the front end of things, in a quick paced environment. I honestly felt more important in my previous position but I do not want to sabotage myself in this new position as well.

I'm unsure if this change has made me realize where I want to be within this company and department I want to grow in. That I let my frustrations get the best of me during a transition period and I could have been apart of the changes to come. Maybe I'm just having a hard time getting used to the new job.

While it is actually not uncommon in my company for people to move back to old departments I feel embarrassed and guilty now if I bring my concerns to someone. My leaving has been hard on my two coworkers who have now been down a person and it caught most off guard because I did not speak up about my frustrations.

Is it ok to bring these concerns up to a manager or my HR person? I'm worried to look unreliable but I was told before leaving my old position and during my review if I do not speak up I can not be helped.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the role, I've found it often takes anywhere from 6 months to a full year to really find your footing after starting a new role. It is can especially be hard going from a role where you felt like you knew everything to one were you are back to learning. So the fact that you are feeling like you are having trouble adjusting and like you aren't contributing to as high a degree as you were before is normal. Three months is not enough time to get acclimated to a new job. Cut yourself a break and give yourself time before you make any hasty decisions. Remind yourself of how this new position will help advance your career and lead to better things in the future.

If you are facing any particular challenges your manager can clear up, by all means bring it to them. What you were told is correct, if you don't speak up you can't be helped. You won't be viewed as unreliable for doing so (in fact, it would be much worse if you needed help and didn't ask for it). I wouldn't talk about going back to your old role unless you are really serious about seeking that route - and I will stress again, give yourself some time before doing so - but anything that is giving you trouble should be brought up. If your manager is even halfway good, they will want to help.

Answer (score 1):

Do you **really** want your old position back? Because if not, there's no need to bring it up in front of HR.

For me, it looks like you're just having a small but common issue of acclimating to the new position; To help, try to see the better sides of the new position - it's a promotion (so I understand), and you're learning new things which might be very useful for you in the future of your career. This is good since it can be a significant entry in your resume, while getting back to your older position will hinder the progress you've begun to accumulate.

My suggestion is to always advance forward, and never look back. Most cases this is the best option and the one which also pays better, and in the worst case - you just look for a new position in another company, bringing with you new advanced experience and better set of skills.

Comment: new is always better - Barney Stinson